# Connection refused error when trying to communicate between two virtualbox machines for node app and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ansible

I have the following setup for servers (VMs), nodejs on one, mongodb on one, frontend on one and the ansible master controller on the last one. My nodejs app won't talk to the mongodb vm, but I can ping the mongodb vm from the nodejs vm.

Here is my mongodb 'mongo.conf' file:

```
# mongodb.conf                                                                                                       
# Where to store the data.                                                                                        
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true                                                         
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.56.11                                                                          
port = 27017
# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling       
journal=true                               
# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait  
#cpu = true                                                                                                         
# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default  
#noauth = true 
auth = true                                                                                                           
# Verbose logging output.
verbose = true                                                                                                        
# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers) 
#objcheck = true                                                                                                 
# Enable db quota management  
#quota = true                                                                                                         
# Set diagnostic logging level where n is 
#   0=off (default)                                                                                                      [44/1060]
#   1=W  
#   2=R    
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads 
#diaglog = 0                                                                                                           
# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true                                                                                                 
# Ignore query hints       
#nohints = true                                                                                                      
# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
#nohttpinterface = true                                                                                        
# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality           
#noscripting = true                                                                                              
# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.  
#notablescan = true  
# Disable data file preallocation.  
#noprealloc = true                                                                                                  
# Specify .ns file size for new databases.  
# nssize = <size>                                                                                                 
# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.  
#mms-token = <token>                                                                                        
# Server name for Mongo monitoring server. 
#mms-name = <server-name>                                                                          
# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server. 
#mms-interval = <seconds>                                                                              
# Replication Options                                                                                         
# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master                                                   
#slave = true   
#source = master.example.com 
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate 
#only = master.example.com                                                                                                [0/1060]
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com

# Address of a server to pair with.
#pairwith = <server:port>
# Address of arbiter server.
#arbiter = <server:port>
# Automatically resync if slave data is stale
#autoresync
# Custom size for replication operation log.
#oplogSize = <MB>
# Size limit for in-memory storage of op ids.
#opIdMem = <bytes>

# SSL options
# Enable SSL on normal ports
#sslOnNormalPorts = true
# SSL Key file and password
#sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
#sslPEMKeyPassword = pass
```

And the nodejs connection code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || {{ app_port }},
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Post = require('./api/models/postModel'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://{{ appdbuser }}:{{ appdbpass }}@{{ db_host }}:27017/{{ db_name }}?authSource=admin',
        {
             useMongoClient: true

        },
    (err, db) => {
        if (err) console.log('Error', err);
        console.log('Conneted to mongodb');


    }

);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/routes');
routes(app);

app.listen({{ app_port }});

console.log('Application started on: ' + {{ app_port }});
```

Comment: check if you can connect with mongo client to the mongo VM to it its IP: 192.168.56.11:27017 , maybe unblock if you have any firewall set in the mongo VM if it blocks access to the TCP port 27017

Comment: @r2d2 from the mongodb vm or the node vm?

Comment: try first from mongodb VM to access the IP address ( not localhost) , if it works than copy the mongo shell client to your app VM and try from there ...

Comment: @r2d2 that's it chief I was able to resolve it thanks. If you could post an answer that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

As reported , the connection string had to be tested and updated with the correct values.

Comment: The solution was to test the connection strings and I was able to see the issue and it was the connection string. Update your answer accordingly and I will accept it.